# VBO verses Vertex Array, vertex normals issue in VBO

Tags: opengl, vbo, normals

I don't know what's wrong here, everything is working fine except normals.
When I use vertex array, model looks perfect but when I switch to VBO, model looks worse because of vertex normals. I spent a lot of time to fix it but do not know what's wrong. VBO generation seems perfect. but still do not know.
any idea?

```
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))


void InitVBO(){

glGenBuffers(1, &vboNormID); 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboNormID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLpoint)*nb_Vertices, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLpoint)*nb_Vertices, VertNormals);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLpoint), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

glGenBuffers(1, &vboVertID); 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertID); 
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLpoint)*nb_Vertices, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLpoint)*nb_Vertices, p_VERTICES);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLpoint), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));


glGenBuffers(1, &indexVBOID); 
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBOID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLFace)*nb_Faces, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLFace)*nb_Faces, p_indices);

//glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLFace)*nb_Faces, p_indices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);}
```

Rendering code is followed. VBO + Vertex Array
Vertex array is working perfect. I can see the perfect shape of model with vertex normals, but with VBO there is some issue with vertex normals. I think I am doing something wrong with BUFFER_OFFSET(12).

```
void RenderTringularModel(GLvoid){
if(VertNormals && !MESH_SMOOTH)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboNormID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBOID);

    glPushClientAttrib( GL_CLIENT_VERTEX_ARRAY_BIT );
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLpoint), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLpoint), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, nb_Faces*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glPopClientAttrib();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}
else
{
    //glShadeModel (GL_FLAT);
    glPushClientAttrib( GL_CLIENT_VERTEX_ARRAY_BIT );
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLpoint), p_VERTICES);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,  sizeof(GLpoint), VertNormals);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3*nb_Faces, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, p_indices);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glPopClientAttrib();
}
```

}

**UPDATE 1:**
I think you are talking about InitVBO.. I was wrong at that point. How about this...But it is also not working.. actually the issue it.. in many ways i tried to bind the vertex normals in InitVBO().. but result comes the same every time.

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboVertID); 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertID); 
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLpoint)*nb_Vertices, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLpoint)*nb_Vertices, p_VERTICES);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLpoint)*nb_Vertices, sizeof(GLpoint)*nb_Vertices, VertNormals);  
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLpoint), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLpoint), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
```

**Update 2:**
Ok ... i don't bind the vertex normals (vboNormID). I am discarding it. is it ok now ? Now it should work.. Actually i have done everything in that way.. to bind the vertex normals with vboVertID and with vboNormID etc etc.. but not every single mathod is working.. give me any suggestion by analyzing this code.

```
    void RenderTringularModel(GLvoid){
if(VertNormals && !MESH_SMOOTH)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBOID);

    glPushClientAttrib( GL_CLIENT_VERTEX_ARRAY_BIT );
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLpoint), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLpoint), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, nb_Faces*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

**Update 3:**

I don't know who told me to use BUFFER_OFFSET()... just crap.. I have fixed it now, now working fine without this stupid BUFFER_OFFSET().. 
Now the fixed code it really simple as follows:

```
void InitVBO(){
glGenBuffers(1, &vboVertID); 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertID); 
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLpoint)*nb_Vertices, p_VERTICES, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &vboNormID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboNormID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLpoint)*nb_Vertices, VertNormals, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &indexVBOID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBOID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLFace)*nb_Faces, p_indices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);}


void RenderTringularModel(GLpoint *P, GLpoint *Vn, GLFace *T, int nbF){
glPushClientAttrib( GL_CLIENT_VERTEX_ARRAY_BIT );
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertID);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboNormID);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBOID);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, nb_Faces*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glPopClientAttrib();}
```

Now guys kindly guide me how can I update these buffers in real-time. I mean to say I need to update the whole data in real-time, normals, vertices, triangles.
for example: after subdivision of triangles, i would need to update the triangles buffer with vertices and normals too.. and another thing is, during cutting simulation of model, i need to update the vertices position and normals, so i would need to update the buffer at that point too.. so tell what do i do for this kind of issue ? how can i make it up ? do i need to delete the buffers and regenerate again ? if yes then how ?

Comment: You're binding two things to the same target at once, and only after that using glXXXPointer calls. The first thing isn't bound anymore. It may seem nice to group the call by type, but you can't - you'll have to group them by "thing they work on". Also why are there offsets and strides at all when you're using separate buffers anyway?

Comment: I think you are talking about InitVBO();

Comment: No that one sets things up a bit oddly, but actually gets the NormalPointer and VertexPoint pretty much right (that offset looks weird though). The problem that I see is in RenderTringularModel, in the first 5 lines.

Comment: What is `sizeof(GLpoint)`? Aren't the normal components tightly packed? (`stride = 0`). Why the offset of 12 bytes?

Comment: Ok now you're putting the vertices and normals in the same VBO.. but it's too small. It has to be twice as big. Nevermind the glXPointer in the init.. just do it in the draw, and then not with offset 12 (this was from the example on opengl.org right?) because it doesn't have an offset of 12, it has an offset of `sizeof(GLpoint)*nb_Vertices`.

Comment: In response to your latest edit, that's kind of a new question really. You can just overwrite the data (see glBufferData, glBufferSubData or gl(Un)MapBuffer), *but* the new data obviously has to be as large or smaller than the size of the buffer. It if has to grow, delete it and create a new one.

Comment: I just realized that I was quite unclear there - glBufferData with a null pointer for `data` deletes the old data and gives you a new buffer of the new size. No need to glDeleteBuffers it.